# Dependent and Independent events - card selections

Tags: probability, independence

We have two players (Alan and Bob) and we have a standard deck of 52 cards. We give 5 cards to each of them. Decide if event A and event B is dependent.

- Event A - player Alan was given three tens and two nines.
- Event B -    player Bob was given spades ten, spades queen, spades ten,
  spades nine,    spades jack.

  P(B) = C(52,5)

Comment: I do not understand your calculation of P(A)

Comment: I am sorry, I mean P(B) = There are C(52,5)

Comment: Think without calculations about $P(B|A)$ vs $P(B)$. If A happens, there is a high chance A has either heart queen or heart 10 - which reduces probability of B, i.e. $P(B)>P(B|A)$. Hence events are not independent and are negatively associated.

Comment: Yes, events are probably not independent, however I need to prove it by calculations.

Answer (score 2):

$$P(A)=\frac {\binom 4 3 \cdot \binom 4 2 }{\binom {52} 5}$$
$$P(A|B)=\frac {\binom 3 3 \cdot \binom 3 2 }{\binom {47} 5}$$

Comment: The ratio is 24.(43/48).(44/49).(45/50).(46/51).(47/52) which is greater than 1 (different from 1 would have been enough to answer the question).

Answer (score 0):

I'd compute the first probability through combinatorics. The number of ordered hands with three queens and two tens are $\binom 4 3 \cdot \binom 4 2$: you must choose three queens out of the possible four, two tens out of the possible four. Hence, the probability of event $A$ is

$$P(A)=\frac {\binom 4 3 \cdot \binom 4 2  }{\binom {52} 5}$$

The probability of event $B$ can be easily calculated noticing that the probability of a certain card getting drawed is $\frac 1 {52}$. You draw the first card: the probability that this card is a king of hearts, queen of hearts, ten of hearts, nine of hearts or jack of hearts is $\frac{5}{52}$. When you draw the second card, the probability is $\frac 4{51}$, because only $4$ cards out of the remaining $51$ will do. Iterating this procedure leads to

$$P(B)=\frac{5\cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48}$$

This has little to do with the question stated in the exercise, though. The events are clearly dependent. We say that $A$,$B$ are independent if $P(A|B)=P(A)$: this is not the case. In fact, if Alan was given $3$ of the $4$ queens, the probability that Bob will receive the queen of hearts is reduced significantly.

Comment: I don't really understand the permutation (5!)

Comment: Brain fart. I'll edit.

Comment: Anyways, thank you from the bottom of my heart.